# Определение платежной системы у пластиковой карты

Tags: c++

Имеется номер пластиковой карты, предположим: 4276123456789100.

Имеется список платежных систем и их идентификаторов:

- Visa - 4
- MasterCard - 51, 52, 53, 54, 55
- Maestro - 5018, 5020, 5038, 5893, 6304, 6759, 6761- 6763
- и т.д.

Список довольно большой и, естественно, ифами это делать не вариант. Вопрос заключается в том, как архитектурно реализовать данную проверку.

Comment: Делайте if`ами.

Comment: можно задать словарь, например в файле, и в цикле прогнать

Comment: Имеет место быть

Comment: Использовать пример готовой библиотеки: https://github.com/braintree/credit-card-type

Comment: Вопрос на SO: [How do you detect Credit card type based on number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72768/how-do-you-detect-credit-card-type-based-on-number)

Answer (score 1):

Можно и `if`'ами. Будет примерно такое:

```
bool startsWith(std::string mainStr, std::string toMatch) {
    return mainStr.find(toMatch) == 0;
}

string pan = "4276123456789100";

if (startsWith(pan, "4")) {
    cout << "Visa";

} else if (startsWith(pan, "51") || startsWith(pan, "52") || ...) {
    cout << "MasterCard";

} else if ...
```

Comment: Это довольна неплохой вариант, за исключением одного: Discover - 6011, 622126 — 622925, 644-649, 65

Comment: Сделать функцию, которая принимает в себя пан и диапазон. Диапазон разворачивается в цикле и каждое значение в цикле приводится к строке и через startsWith проверяется. Если хоть что-то в цикле сработало -- карта Discover

Comment: а в чем проблема вместо сравнивания строк сравнивать цифры? Берем нужное количество цифр с начала и прогоняем по всем диапазонам, с цифрами это будет простое сравнение n > 622126 & n < 622925

Comment: @goldstar_labs, проблемы нет, мой пример первое что пришло в голову. Оформите предложенный вами алгоритм в ответ, хуже не станет :)

Answer (score 1):

Я не знаю как по номеру пластиковой карты находят платежную систему, но сделал какие то  предположения, исходя из первого ответа.  Весь смысль в том, что нужно избавляться от  мышления по направлению структурного программирования и ориентироваться на ООП. Использовать преимущества ООП (C++). Я тут побыстрому написал примерный код, который можно конечно оптимизировать:
Вы правы в том, что не желаете использовать структуру if/else ов. Поскольку это особенно неудобно, если систем будет много...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>
struct Range {
    std::vector<std::string> data;
    Range(const int first, int last = 0)
    {
        if(!last)
            data.emplace_back(std::to_string(first));
        else if (last > first)
            for (int i = first; i <= last; ++i)
                data.emplace_back(std::to_string(i));
    }
};
using Map =  std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> ;
void insertRange(const std::string& s, const Range& r, Map& m)
{
    for (auto& i : r.data)
        m.emplace(std::make_pair(i, s));

}
const std::string search_system(const std::string s, const Map& m)
{
    for (auto& i : m) {
       if (s.find(i.first) != std::string::npos)
       return i.second;
    }
    return "no such system";
}

int main()
{  
    Map payment_systems;
    const std::string s = "4276123456789100";
    insertRange("Visa", Range(4), payment_systems);
    insertRange("MasterCard", Range(51, 55), payment_systems);
    insertRange("Maestro", Range(5018), payment_systems);
    //...
    insertRange("Maestro", Range(6761, 6763), payment_systems);
    std::cout << search_system(s, payment_systems);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А причем тут ООП? У вас же просто использование map, его можно было бы реализовать и без ООП, ну пришлось бы вместо  m.emplace(std::make_pair(i, s)); писать emlace(&m,std::make_pair(i, s)); , но на саму структуру данных это бы не повлияло.

Comment: Это имеет место быть, но слишком уж громоздка и тяжело для такой задачи. Ответ написанный ниже был куда более элегантен и не требует ничего лишнего.

Comment: Да,  если вам нужно проверить всего три значения.  А если таких   значений  сотни, вы  предпочитаете писать сто  таких условмий, это ваше дело

Comment: Вы хотите, чтобы я в Range записал 799 значений, когда это можно сделать циклом. Тот же недочет, что и в предыдущем ответе.